# Why is torch.clamp in pytorch not working?

Tags: python, pytorch

When I was training my nn, something really wired happened.

```py
res = torch.clamp(res_not_clamp, 0.0, 1.0)
if torch.isnan(res).any() or res.max()> 1.0 :
    raise ValueError("NAN! Stop Training")
```

Here `torch.clamp` is supposed to limit the value of `res`, but it still raises the ValueError.

I insert a breakpoint here at the `raise` line.  When it was triggered, some exprs are below:

```
res.max()
> tensor(8.4190e+23)

res.flatten().sort()[0][-5:]
> tensor([5.9186e+04, 5.9186e+04, 8.4190e+23, 8.4190e+23, 8.4190e+23])

torch.clamp(res_not_clamp, 0.0, 1.0).max()
>tensor(0.8616)
```

That was soooooo wierd. I wonder what happened here.

More:
I try to modify it to:

```py
res = torch.minimum(torch.ones_like(res_not_clamp), res_not_clamp)
res = torch.maximum(torch.zeros_like(res), res)
if torch.isnan(res).any() or res.max()> 1.0 :
   raise ValueError("NAN! Stop Training")
```

It just still raises that error! Soooooooooooooo wierd!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with an input example and expected output. It's not clear where you set the breakpoint exactly, `clamp` will not clamp `nan` values.

Comment: @Michael Szczesny Hard to make it.  This situation only shows up when I use AMP.  I set the breakpoint at the `raise` line.

Answer (score 0):

torch.clamp does not modify the possible nan values in your data, they will still be nan after the clamp.

So what's probably happening is that the first part of your if (`torch.isnan(res).any()`) is triggering the raise of the ValueError.

Comment: But `torch.isnan(res).any()` returned False.  I inspected the memory of the tensor, and I found the value of deviant is odd like `0x69C3636D`,  while the values near its address are all `0x0000803F`(1.0 in Float32).  After I re-excute the clamp expr in debugger and inspect the new result in the same way,  the value of origin deviant address is amazingly    `0x0000803F`! Whhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhy?????